# Random number with fixed length

Tags: javascript, random

I want to generate a random integer number with 0-9 numbers and with length = 5. I try this:

```
function genRand(min,max) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        var range = max - min + 1;
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*range) + min;
    }
}
```

and call:

```
genRand(0,9);
```

But it always returns 1 number, not 5 (

Help please!

Comment: So, you want a random, 5-digit integer is what you are saying? It's not clear.

Comment: generate randomly 5 single digits from 0 to 9 and paste them

Comment: "paste"? Could you include some desired results of what you want the function to return? String "07198" or Array (Object) [0,7,1,9,8] ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
   function genRand() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random()*89999+10000);
   }
```

Comment: Why do you use 89999?

Comment: Math.random returns a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). Therefore you could instead do Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000 as you're guaranteed never to generate 90000.

Comment: @OscarLópez 89999 comes from the maximum 5 digit number possible (99999) - the lowest 5 digit number possible (10000)

Answer (score 9):

`return` exits the function on the first loop.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest 5 digit number is 10000, the largest is 99999, or 10000+89999.

Return a random number between 0 and 89999, and add it to the minimum.

```
var ran5=10000+Math.round(Math.floor()*90000)
```

Math.floor rounds down, and Math.random is greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more generalized version of Nate B's answer:

```
function rand(digits) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*parseInt('8' + '9'.repeat(digits-1))+parseInt('1' + '0'.repeat(digits-1)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a 5 digit random number generate random numbers between the range (10000, 99999). Or generate randomly 5 single digits and paste them.

**EDIT**

The process you have shown simply will generate one number and return to the caller. The think which might work is (pseudo code) :

```
int sum = 0;
int m = 1;
for (i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  sum = sum  + m * random (0, 9);
  /*       or                  */
  sum = sum * m + random (0, 9);
  m = m * 10;
}
```

Or better generate 5 digit random numbers with `rand (10000, 99999)`

Comment: "generate randomly 5 single digits from 0 to 9 and paste them" YES!

Comment: isn't it better to simply generate random numbers within the range (10000, 99999) ?? For pasting the 5 randomly generated digits (0 to 9) you need to perform 5 multiplications and 5 additions.